# How to call IoT Core registerThing for another account?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-iot, aws-iot-core

I have a lambda. This lambda creates a thing by doing something like:

```
const cfnThing = new iot.CfnThing(this, 'MyCfnThing', /* all optional props */ {
  attributePayload: {
    attributes: {
      attributesKey: 'attributes',
    },
  },
  thingName: 'thingName',
});
```

But I want to create a thing on a different account. I created a role so it can be assumed. But I don't understand how to change credentials for the thing creation operation. I found that for s3 operations it can be done by putting new credentials to the client. Is there a client for iot too? Is there any other way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first need to create a role in the destination account. Then in your lambda, in source account, you need to assume the role. Here is a piece of code I'm using to assume the role with automatic refresh of the credentials:

This is the credentials.py:

```
import boto3
from botocore.credentials import RefreshableCredentials
from boto3 import Session
from botocore.session import get_session



def refreshed_session(role_arn, region='eu-central-1'):
    """Assume a boto3.Session With automatic credential renewal.
    Args:
        region (str, optional): The region of the session.
                                Defaults to 'eu-central-1'.
    Returns:
        session (Session): an boto3 session with RefreshableCredentials
    """
    def _refresh():
        " Refresh tokens by calling assume_role again "
        params = {
            "RoleArn": role_arn,
            "RoleSessionName": "cross_acct_lambda",
            "DurationSeconds": 3600,
        }
        sts_client = boto3.client("sts", region_name='eu-central-1')
        response = sts_client.assume_role(**params).get("Credentials")
        credentials = {
            "access_key": response.get("AccessKeyId"),
            "secret_key": response.get("SecretAccessKey"),
            "token": response.get("SessionToken"),
            "expiry_time": response.get("Expiration").isoformat(),
        }
        return credentials

    session_credentials = RefreshableCredentials.create_from_metadata(
        metadata=_refresh(),
        refresh_using=_refresh,
        method="sts-assume-role",
    )

    session = get_session()
    session._credentials = session_credentials
    session.set_config_variable("region", region)

    return Session(botocore_session=session)
```

And then in lambda you can use it like this:

```
# create service client using the assumed role credentials, e.g. iot-data
boto3_session = credentials.refreshed_session(account_destination_role_arn)
iot_client = boto3_session.client('iot-data')
```

Any call to AWS IoT Control Plane API using `iot_client` will be on the destination account.